# allow .php extension in htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am using this htaccess code to check login and download any direct hot link file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  /includes/put_file.php?dir=laudos&file=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

my problem is i want to skeep .php extension files just want to check .jpg, .doc etc document kind of files

Comment: Sorry I think I misread you question.

Comment: Can you clarify? You want to skeep .php and check for what?

Comment: @PanamaJack sir I want to check SESSION in put_file.php 

In that case if you have URL(HOTLINK) of any document then you can not download it or you can not share it ....
So if you dont have permission of document you can not download it 
but unfortunately.... in same folder I have some php code written So I want to skip this php files to check SESSION and I want to redirect direct to PHP files ....
Hope You are getting my problem

Comment: Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /includes/put_file.php?dir=laudos&file=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like that

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(jpg|doc))$ /includes/put_file.php?dir=laudos&file=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Sorry not working .....It is going to same page put_file.php if .php request find

Comment: Strange... Just checked it and it worked... It only redirected jpg and doc files. Did you replace your last line with mine? Or you just appended it?

Comment: I replace your List line in my htaccess file not append

Comment: Hello @spaceman Sir it works for php files I need to check for .doc files

Comment: Hello! Try the second answer by Panama Jack to see if it works for you. If you want to allow only specific file types replace `!\.(php)$` with `\.(doc|jpg)$` in his code.

Comment: Sir both answers are working But I used from PanamaJeck thats why I accept this but I requests to my Colleague to like your both answers....